# Codeigniter move to different controller after successful login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a login page at http:localhost/my project. After successful authentication with the server I want to redirect to a view which I put in another controller(search_controller) called search.php. I am able to successfully load my search view after authentication. The problem is I have another form in search.php and on submission of form I get 'object not found'.

here is my code.
localhost/myproject
Default Controller: Welcome

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->login();
}
 public function login() {
    $data['title'] = 'Login Form';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'required|trim');
    //other form validation rules
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    } else {
        $data['title'] = 'login form';
        $username = $this->input->post('user');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $company = $this->input->post('xdetail');
     // authentication from server
        if(somecondition)
        $this->load->view('search');
    }
}
```

I am able to view content on search page. Now I have another form for in this view and I wrote this in another container.
Container:Search_Controller

```
class Search_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->search();
}

public function search() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'valid_email');
    //form validation rules
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('search');
    } else {
        //get search Paraments here and put it in $data;
         $this->load->view('search', $data);
    }
}
}
```

Now when I click submit button I get object not found.
In search view I have the following code

```
//HTML script
echo validation_errors();
            echo form_fieldset('Search Form');

            $attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform1',    'name'=>'sform');
            echo form_open('',$attributes);
            $emaildata=array(
            'name'=>'email',
            'id'=>'email_id',
            'class'=>'email_class',
            'size'=>'50',
            'style'=>'width:150px'
            );
            $firstNamedata=array(
            //attributes
            );
            $lastNamedata=array(
            //attributes
            );
            echo'<label for="email">Email ID</label><br>'.form_input($emaildata).'<br>';
            echo'<label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>'.form_input($firstNamedata).'<br>';
            echo'<label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br>'.form_input($lastNamedata).'<br>';
            echo br();
            echo form_submit('mysubmit1','search');
            echo form_close();
            echo form_fieldset_close();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

UPDATE:

My .htaccess is:

```
IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IFModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What object isn't found? You need to add specific error codes, and what you are trying to do. I see many errors, you're not loading codeigniter's form helper for example, so `form_open()` wont work

Comment: I loaded all the helpers and libraries in autoload. The complete error is "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30"

Comment: whats your `$config['base_url']` value? What's your url structure? Your `vhost/htaccess`?

Comment: In config.php I put $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/myproject/"; $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: first, change the `base_url` to `http://localhost/myproject/` (or https), if you have no index, you'll need to let us see your htaccess/vhost.

Comment: @Kisaragi I have updated the htaccess above, I put the http before the localhost but it not showing it here

Comment: @Kisaragi My bad did not use the proper formatting here in the comments

Comment: You've still not shown us your url structure

Comment: @Kisaragi I did not exactly understand what you mean by URI structure. I have updated my question above with the .htaccess values I used.

Comment: <!--$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE; --> this is routes.php @Kisaragi

Answer (score 1):

Put a redirect in controller after you login sucessfully like this :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->login();
}
 public function login() {
    $data['title'] = 'Login Form';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'required|trim');
    //other form validation rules
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    } else {
        $data['title'] = 'login form';
        $username = $this->input->post('user');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $company = $this->input->post('xdetail');
     // authentication from server
        if(somecondition)

        redirect('search');
        $this->load->view('search');
    }
}
```